# How can I check how many times I've been suspended?

Tags: support, account-suspension

I have been suspended once before, four years ago. Now, unfortunately, once again. One of the mods claims that it's been three times, which I don't recall. I asked about clarification but was faced with a wall of silence.

I see no point cheating and it's quite embarrassing to be suspended for sock-puppetry but I do understand the situation. However, I do take offense when someone (especially a mod, which is a honorary status, in my view) creates the aura of constant misbehavior over me, implying that I'm breaking the rules frequently etc.

Then, not responding after making false claims is in my view simply rude. I understand mods are people with lives too and that needs to be respected. However, mods did put their candidatures and they did applied for the role, which implies certain responsibilities.

Before making an complaint, I wish to ensure that I'm not mistaken and that my claim is supported by fact. Hence the question—how can I verify that the number of suspensions claimed is incorrect?

Comment: Just look for large negative values in your rep graph.  Puppets were removed on Mar 13 2013 and Mar 29 2013.  Sep 17 2012 had a large "normal" serial voting correction.  Mar 25 2015 and Oct 11 2016 could be puppet removals as well.

Comment: @HansPassant Great. Then it's confirmed. Thank you.   :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get sent an email for every *normal* suspension. So, if you don't delete them, you'll have a record in your archives.

This doesn't work for unusual types of suspensions (those that apply network-wide or involve account deletion), but if either of those ever applies to you then all bets are off anyway; realistically, you're probably not going to be asking.

FWIW, you've been suspended twice. I don't see any record of a moderator telling you differently; it's possible you emailed a moderator privately and he replied from memory, but I have no knowledge of this (and, really, you shouldn't do that if you want an "official" reply).

Comment: Well, I don't really keep email for 4 years, so the record is all gone. The false claim was made in public comment and referred to me being suspended **twice before**, while still under suspension. He had another false claim (which actually addressed the ban). To that, I got no reply neither (waited for two weeks or something). It's hard to help the mod correct the mistakes if they don't reply. I keep it patient and polite but get false claims back. It makes me sad.

Comment: Again, I have no way of verifying this; I see no evidence on-site.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - [here you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/286674/195875), first and second paragraphs from the bottom.

Comment: Brad said you were suspended *once* before, and **warned** again after that @Konrad. One suspension (Sept. 2012), one warning (Mar. 2013).

Comment: You're correct. I must have reacted to how it sounds, like if I'm doing it all the time (which I don't). I don't recall a warning but it must be 2012 too, at the same time, when I got into argument with a colleague and dared him to prove that SO is flawed, hehe. He kind of did... Now, it's a new job, different firm, new people and one of them got carried away. I'm pretty sure which one but when I checked, he didn't only vote on me but others too (still not OK to vote on a person instead of on the answer). He's going to be booted for it too. Thanks a lot for the help understanding, mate!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **"contact us"** link at the bottom of every Stack Overflow page.

I doubt that this information is available to anyone other than a moderator, community manager, or employee.

Being that you cannot—or should not even if you can—contact a moderator or community manager directly, submitting a request directly to the Stack Overflow team may be the best option.

I see no value in making this information readily available.

Comment: "I see no value in making this information readily available." Why not? Why it's not possible to check that without contacting SO team?

Comment: I agree. It's a bit of a special case. A mod has made a false claim twice. Each time, when I point that out and ask for verification, I get silence. I'm considering making a complaint but I wish to tripple-check so that I'm not mistaken. Hence the question.